# What is the use of SNAP-SHOT version in maven while creating maven project?

Tags: maven

[image]

I got a question while creating maven project that why we are specifying value to SNAP-SHOT text box in maven project.

Please give me some idea reg above question.

Answer (score 1):

In every artifacts, there are some stable release and there are some unstable  named as "SNAPSHOT".

It refers to the latest release of the current development(branch). It's not an official stable release with no guarantee. You can produce the snapshot with every commit. SNAPSHOT is followed by RELEASE.
It's preferable to use the stable releases.

Source : [What is a SNAPSHOT version?](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#What_is_a_SNAPSHOT_version)